# EntityFramework Parent Child on same table loads very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

this Is my Class: TimePart.

```
    public class TimePart : IEntity, IComposite<TimePart>
    {
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual TimePart Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TimePart> Children { get; set; }
    .......+some other properties
    public TimePart()
    {
        Children = new List<TimePart>();

    }

    public virtual TimePart Root
    {
        get
        {
            if (Parent == null)
                return this;
            TimePart root = Parent;
            int levels = 0;
            while (root.Parent != null && levels < 50)
            {
                root = root.Parent;
                levels++;
            }
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my dbContext

```
 public class DbContextFlex : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public DbContextFlex(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TimePart>().HasOptional(m => m.Parent)
           .WithMany(m => m.Children)
           .HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentId);

    }

    public DbSet<TimePart> Timeparts { get; set; }
    .....with other dbsets.....
```

Here is my Problem. the following line takes about 26 seconds to load 90 rows with there childeren and the childeren there childeren....

```
   var tp = Helpers.DbContext.Timeparts.ToList().Single(t => t.Id == simpleTp.Id);
```

If i remove the ToList and change my code like :

```
   var tp = Helpers.DbContext.Timeparts.Single(t => t.Id == simpleTp.Id);
```

I don't get al the childeren and theire childeren....

Comment: Have you done any profiling on this or looked at the generated SQL?

Comment: The first statement loads *all* Timeparts from the database. You should use the second statement with `Include`s.

Comment: `var tp = Helpers.DbContext.Timeparts.ToList().Single(t => t.Id == simpleTp.Id);`
This will load every `Timepart` in your DB and only return one in the end.
`var tp = Helpers.DbContext.Timeparts.Single(t => t.Id == simpleTp.Id);`
This is the one you are looking for.
Like @GertArnold said, try loading it with `Include` operations.
Otherwise you might need to concider doing a direct SQL / StoredProcedure query. Have a look at Recursive CTE's (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I already tried using a include but that only returns the child of that timepart. It doesn't look if these childeren also has childeren.

I know a can have a workaround with a direct SQL/ StoredProcedure but I want to avoid that and check if there is a way with entityframework.

Comment: I think that is where turning off Proxy creation (`Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`) has prevented you from loading your children's children. I don't think EF does a FULL hierarchy loading with eager loading. I don't know the details of EF to be able to answer that.
However here are two articles I've found that might assist:
http://codingcanvas.com/loading-nested-entities-in-entityframework/ and 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management

Comment: Another interesting thing is that you can do an Include on a property with a collection and do a select on that. Maybe that is something for you to try out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943942/loading-nested-entities-collections-with-entity-framework